# Buscar tags em json com REGEXP ignorando acentuações

Tags: mysql, sql

Como posso ignorar os acentos com regexp? com LIKE estava funcionando, porem estava tendo problema com posts cujo numero de tags era grande.

```
SELECT id, JSON_EXTRACT(quiz_json, '$.tags') from quiz_publico where aprovado = 1 AND JSON_EXTRACT(quiz_json, '$.tags') REGEXP 'Desenhos|Series'
```

Exemplo a tag Series pode existir com ou sem acento no banco de dados e preciso retornar das 2 formas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente não pode. `REGEXP` utiliza o byte do caractere, o seu código, o que diferencia caracteres acentuados e não acentuados, pois cada um tem um código diferente.

Já tive esse problema, e encontrei essa reposta do SO em inglês: [MySQL REGEXP query - accent insensitive search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14137335/4730201)
, e lá ele cita um link da documentação do `MySQL`: [MySQL REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html), que tem esse texto:

> **Warning** The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so they are not multibyte safe and may produce unexpected results with
>   multibyte character sets. In addition, these operators compare
>   characters by their byte values and accented characters may not
>   compare as equal even if a given collation treats them as equal.

Em tradução livre:

> Os operadores REGEXP e RLIKE funcionam de "maneira byte", portanto, não
>   são seguros para multibytes e podem produzir resultados inesperados
>   com conjuntos de caracteres multibyte. Além disso, esses operadores
>   comparam caracteres por seus valores de bytes e caracteres acentuados
>   não podem ser comparados como iguais*("e" não é igual a "é" por exemplo)*, mesmo que um determinado
>   agrupamento os trate como iguais.

Comment: Aparentemente funcionou, coloquei uma função no php pra substituir acentos por por rules de expressões regulares, function substituirAcentos($string){
    return preg_replace(array("/(á|à|ã|â|ä)/","/(Á|À|Ã|Â|Ä)/","/(é|è|ê|ë)/","/(É|È|Ê|Ë)/","/(í|ì|î|ï)/","/(Í|Ì|Î|Ï)/","/(ó|ò|õ|ô|ö)/","/(Ó|Ò|Õ|Ô|Ö)/","/(ú|ù|û|ü)/","/(Ú|Ù|Û|Ü)/","/(ñ)/","/(Ñ)/"), 
    explode(" ","(á|à|ã|â|ä) (Á|À|Ã|Â|Ä) (é|è|ê|ë) (É|È|Ê|Ë) (í|ì|î|ï) (Í|Ì|Î|Ï) (ó|ò|õ|ô|ö) (Ó|Ò|Õ|Ô|Ö) (ú|ù|û|ü) (Ú|Ù|Û|Ü) (ñ) (Ñ)"), $string);
}

Comment: sim, se substituir ou incluir todas as variações para comparar vai funcionar